# Square Wave with Overshoot

Tags: noise, square

I'm generating an AC square wave output waveform with the 555 timer circuit below. However, I'm getting these obvious overshoots. Can anyone help me?

R1 is 8.2K ohm
R2 is 68k ohm
C1 is 0.1uF

[image: The 555 Timer Circuit]

[image: The Output Waveform]

Comment: Take a picture of your setup.

Comment: I'm bored, so a small explanation: it's quite high frequency phenomenon. May be caused by bad measurement (like very long ground) or by bad layout (if you even have pcb). Also by not calibrated probe. What is interesting is why don't you see same overshoot on bottom side.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, or even undershoot on the bottom side.

Comment: What does the supply voltage (on pins 4 and 8) look like?

Comment: It acts as if you have an inductive load between the output and +12V. Anything you have omitted telling us?

Comment: add a capacitor between supply pin and ground pin, close to the 555 chip. Value isn't critical: 0.1uf is common.